# Как определить тип ELF файла в Linux?

Tags: elf, linux

Как определить тип ELF файла в Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В заголовке ELF файла есть специальное поле (e_type), предназначенное для задания типа файла. По его значению можно определить тип файла. Например, значение 1 (ET_REL) задает перемещаемый файл.